# Applying a mutating function to an array of imutables

Tags: swift

I have this array extension to remove objects from an array.

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {

    mutating func removeObject(object : Generator.Element) {
        if let index = self.indexOf(object) {
            self.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}
```

I defined a dictionary:

```
var itemsSelected: [NSIndexPath: Item] = [:]
```

Item is an object and when I try to remove it from the dictionary like this:

```
self.itemsSelected.values.array.removeObject(item)
```

I get the following error:

```
Immutable value of type [Base.Generator.Element] only has mutating members named 'removedObject'
```

How can I remove the object from the dictionary ?
I am using Xcode 7 beta 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itemsSelected.values.array` returns an (immutable) array of all
dictionary values, and you cannot use that to modify the original
dictionary.

To remove a given *value* from a dictionary, you can define a 
similar `Dictionary` extension in Swift 2:

```
extension Dictionary where Value : Equatable {

    mutating func removeValue(value : Value) {
        if let index = self.indexOf({ $0.1 == value }) {
            self.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}
```

Here `indexOf()` treats the dictionary as a sequence of key/value
pairs.

But note that if the dictionary has *multiple* keys with the same value then
this will remove just one of them. To remove *all* key/value pairs
with a given value you can replace `if let` by `while let`:

```
extension Dictionary where Value : Equatable {

    mutating func removeValue(value : Value) {
        while let index = self.indexOf({ $0.1 == value }) {
            self.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}
```